# How to write blinking in more elegant way

Tags: javascript, jquery

The aim: to write a js (using jquery) that will perform 2 blinking of the row.

What I currently have is

```
var $second_row = $('table tr:eq(1)'),
    target_color = 'PaleGreen',
    original_color = $second_row.css('background-color');

$second_row.css('background-color', target_color);
scheduleOriginalColor();

function scheduleTargetColor() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $second_row.css('background-color', target_color);
        scheduleOriginalColor(true);
    }, 500);
}

function scheduleOriginalColor(stop) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $second_row.css('background-color', original_color);

        if (!stop) {
            scheduleTargetColor();
        }
    }, 500);
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/ecfMU/1/

But it looks ugly and I'm sure there is a better way of writing the same.

Any proposals?

**UPD**: there is my second attempt, a bit more clear: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/ecfMU/2/

```
var $second_row = $('table tr:eq(1)'),
    target_color = 'PaleGreen',
    original_color = $second_row.css('background-color');

setRowColor(target_color, 500);
setRowColor(original_color, 1000);
setRowColor(target_color, 1500);
setRowColor(original_color, 2000);

function setRowColor(color, timing) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $second_row.css('background-color', color);
    }, timing);
}
​
```

Comment: `<blink>`? Sorry. Couldn't resist. :^)

Comment: @rjz: hehe, nice try ;-)

Comment: @zerkms My updated answer requires/uses no jQuery, and permits you to define both frequency and total number of flashes.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: yep, I seen that and upvoted. But checked solution looks better for me (and other community members)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, using `toggleClass` and a background color:

```
var blink = setInterval(function() {
    $('table tr:eq(1)').toggleClass('highlight');
}, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(blink);
}, 2100); // run 4 times, added a little padding time just in case
```

```
.highlight {
    background-color:PaleGreen;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ecfMU/10/

Comment: If you're using jQuery UI by chance, you might want to look at [highlight](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight) to draw the user's attention to the table row.

Comment: yep, if I could use jquery ui - I'd go with it

Answer (score 7):

The following lets you define the element, color, number of flashes, and speed. Another added benefit is that it doesn't require any of the bloat of jQuery. Always favor raw JavaScript when you can.

```
function flashBG( e, c, x, z ) {
  var d = e.style.backgroundColor, i = 0, f = setInterval(function(){
    e.style.backgroundColor = ( e.style.backgroundColor == d ) ? c : d ;
    ++i == ( x * 2 ) && clearInterval( f );
  }, z );
}
```

Call it like this:

```
flashBG( document.body, "PaleGreen", 2, 500 );
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/axuxiy/3/edit

For readability, the following may be more educational:

```
function flashBG( element, color, flashes, speed ) {
  var original = element.style.backgroundColor;
  var counter  = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(
    function() {
      if ( original === element.style.backgroundColor ) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = color; 
      } else {
        element.style.backgroundColor = original;
      }
      if ( ++counter == ( flashes * 2 ) ) {
        clearInterval( interval );
      }
    }, speed );
}
```

Comment: Almost the same I have in my second version, but thanks anyway

Comment: Looks good, but I loaded your demo when you had the speed at 25ms and almost had a seizure. In any case, I was hypnotized into upvoting.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Yeah, same here - forgot I saved with that freq. The link now points to a much more relaxed demo ;)

Answer (score 3):

Javascript isn't my forte - so I may get a bit of the syntax wrong.

**EDIT: [Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/ecfMU/16/)
EDIT #2: Easily extensible - [rainbow version](http://jsfiddle.net/Fh5N8/)**

However... a very simple way of doing it is have the colors in an array, and an int var with an index. Then have only one scheduled function, like this:

```
//Somewhere else we have:
//var colorArray = blah... blah.. blahh, it has values [palegreen,regularwhite]

//blah blah scheduleColor(0);
//var numBlinks = 2;

//then for your scheduler
function scheduleColor(ind) {
    $second_row.css('background-color', colorArray[ind % colorArray.length]);
    if (ind < (colorArray.length * numBlinks) - 1) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            scheduleColor(ind + 1);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

The basic idea is rather than two schedulers, you have one, that iterates. As a plus, you can easily set it to blink any number of times you want, or cycle through multiple colors.

Heck, if you wanted, you could have it cycle through the rainbow.

*Edited for some syntax/corrections.*

Answer (score 2):

My answer for you is a portmanteau of Wesley's and Ricardo's answers, so I can't take much credit for it.  I'm .delay() and .queue() along with .toggleClass().  I think it ends up a nice bit of code.

Some CSS:

```
.highlight {
    background-color:PaleGreen;
}
```

And the JS:

```
var $second_row = $('table tr:eq(1)');

function blink(el) {
    el.addClass('highlight');
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        el.delay(500).queue(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    }
}

blink($second_row);​
```

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luhn/S7SZM/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var $second_row = $('table tr:eq(1)'),
    target_color = 'PaleGreen',
    original_color = $second_row.css('background-color');


$second_row.css('background-color', target_color).delay(500).queue(function(){
    jQuery(this).css('background-color', original_color);
});
```

Working : **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecfMU/11/)**

Comment: And one more blink please :-)

Answer (score 1):

Can you add jQuery UI?

If so, you can animate the background for a smoother transition.

http://jsfiddle.net/ecfMU/18/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but no, not for this only feature :-)